# How to add project from git to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have an existed eclipse with project from Git in Computer A which is working.

I want to have another station in computer B.

I know that I should do Import -> Import from GIT as instructed here: https://www.lennu.net/import-git-project-into-eclipse/

But this is a project that no one has touched in a long time and I have no idea how to enter the data.

Is there a way to figure out the steps from computer A?

Comment: What don't you know? The git url to clone?

Comment: @Gimby yes that would be the main thing I dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- 1. Use Eclipse to import your project as you described in your question.
- 2. Copy the project (all files / with hidden files) from computer A to computer B and it will work fine as all information GIT needs (history of commits, branches...etc.) are saved in a hidden folder `.git`. Then when you open your project with Eclipse in computer B, it'll know that it's a GIT project!
- 3. Do you know your GIT repository URL? If yes, in your computer B, tape

     `$> git clone <url/to/your/git/repository>`

     Then when you open your project with Eclipse in computer B, it'll know that it's a GIT project!

Comment: How can I find the url of the GIT from computer A?

Comment: @avi using a command line `$> git config --get remote.origin.url`

Comment: use it where? I don't normally work with git. Shouldn't I be able to see the URL from the project itself in Computer A? Where the GIT is installed and working?

Comment: @avi When you are in your *Computer-A* `cd to/your/git/project` and then tape the command

Comment: @avi does it help you?

Comment: nop it says "git is not recognized as an internal or external command". The git installed in my Eclipse as plugin.

Comment: This is because you don't have GIT installed, please take a look https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Eclipse workspace on computer A, figuring out the git url can be done as follows. I can't see that machine, so this answer assumes its a standard Eclipse installation.

1. Open the **git** perspective (window -> perspective -> open perspective)
2. Make sure you're actually looking at the git perspective (should be a button in the top right of the workspace)

The git repositories listing should have an entry which is the git repository the project has been checked out from

3. right click it, select **properties**
4. under **configuration** you should see a property **url** which is the git URL the project was cloned from

And then its fingers crossed that you have access to that git repository so you can clone it out from computer B.